# Checking of duplicate value in JSON object array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this json object which has seq 1,2,3,4. And in the main HTML page, user can edit the seq number and I need to make sure that every seq is unique and must not repeat like 2 set of "1" & "1".
Unfortunately, it is buggy and sometimes it works sometimes not.
Can someone point out my mistake? I want to ignore blank value as well

```
$scope.myDataset.map(v => v.seq).sort().sort((a, b) => {
    if (a !== '' && b !== '' && a === b) {
        $scope.duplicateFound = true
    }
})

$scope.myDataset = [
    { seq: '1', },
    { seq: '2', },
    { seq: '3', },
    { seq: '4', },
    { seq: '', },
    { seq: '', },

];
```

Comment: `sort` for finding a duplicate? this week the same question arised as well. is there somthing promoting it?

Comment: where is the same question may i know?

Comment: Convert it to a Set

Comment: please add some use cases and the wnated result as well.

Comment: Please post your html as well, you could be using an input with type number , which could be mixing with the number chars you have in your json as default.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/aqbbhg8q/

Comment: updated. I do have seq= '' and i do want to ignore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an object as hash table and exclude empty strings.

```js
function hasDupes(array) {
    var hash = Object.create(null);
    return array.some(function (a) {
        return a.seq && (hash[a.seq] || !(hash[a.seq] = true));
    });
}

// false
console.log(hasDupes([{ seq: '4' }, { seq: '1' }, { seq: '2' }, { seq: '7' }, { seq: '6' }, { seq: '5' }]));

// false
console.log(hasDupes([{ seq: '' }, { seq: '1' }, { seq: '' }, { seq: '7' }, { seq: '6' }, { seq: '5' }]));

// true
console.log(hasDupes([{ seq: '4' }, { seq: '1' }, { seq: '2' }, { seq: '4' }, { seq: '3' }, { seq: '4' }]));
```

Comment: i want to ignore empty seq value. only comparing number.

Comment: @user3004237, it does ignore empty string values.

Comment: How can i turn it into a If statement instead? I tried but got stuck. I dont wanna return true or false

Comment: `if (hasDupes(array)) { ... }`?

Comment: Solved. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Following code may be helpful for you:

```js
$scope.myDataset = [
    { seq: '1', },
    { seq: '2', },
    { seq: '3', },
    { seq: '4', },
];
var dataSeq = $scope.myDataset.map(v => v.seq);
dataSeq.forEach(function (item, index) {
  if (item !== '' && dataSeq.indexOf(item) !== index ) {
        $scope.duplicateFound = true;
        break;
    }
 })
```

Comment: First a traditional sort is carried out, so all duplicates would line up together, so they would be next to each other really.

Comment: Yes, i'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `Set` and `array#some`

```js
var myDataset = [
    { seq: '1', },
    { seq: '2', },
    { seq: '3', },
    { seq: '4', },
];

var visited = new Set();
var hasDuplicates = myDataset.some(function(obj) {
    return visited.size === visited.add(obj.seq).size;
});

console.log(Array.from(visited));
console.log(hasDuplicates);
```

Comment: I tried to account for null value   but it cant work  >>>>>>>> return visited.size === visited.add(obj.seq).size && visited.size!=='' && visited.add(obj.seq).size!==''

Comment: Do you mean you can have `seq : null`?

Comment: it can be just seq: ''

Comment: The code will work. You don't have to change anything.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you are somehow mixing Strings and integers, which is why your sort is going wrong. I suggest you modify your mapping function a bit.

```
$scope.myDataset.map(v => parseInt(v.seq + '') ).sort().sort((a, b) => {
    if (a !== '' && b !== '' && a === b) {
        $scope.duplicateFound = true
    }
})
```

Comment: nope not really

Comment: Ok. Would help if you outlined where your code is failing. Theoretically, it seems sound.

Answer (score 0):

I moved the data object above the iteration. Not sure why you were sorting, what the goal was. I added an extra key value pair to the object that you already have to track if it is visited.

In the loop we add another iteration to compare the next element to the current element of the index. To make sure it doesn't go out of the scope of the array we subtract one from the length and when starting the loop we do 'less than' (<), rather than 'less than or equal'(<=) as this would also cause it to go out of the index range of the array.

The visited key will only be true if it was compared to another iteration after itself.

```
$scope.duplicateFound = false;
$scope.myDataset = [
            {
                seq: '1',
                visited: false
            },
            {
                seq: '2',
                visited: false
            },
            {
                seq: '3',
                visited: false
            },
            {
                seq: '4',
                visited: false
            },
            {
                seq: '4',
                visited: false,
            }
        ];

        for (var index = 0; index < $scope.myDataset.length - 1; index++){
           var index2 = index + 1;

           if ($scope.myDataset[index]['visited'] === false && $scope.myDataset[index2]['visited'] === false) {
            if ($scope.myDataset[index]['seq'] == $scope.myDataset[index2]['seq']) {
              $scope.duplicateFound = true;
            }
           }

          $scope.myDataset[index]['visited'] = true;
        }

        console.log($scope)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you like to use Lodash (https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4) JavaScript library then here here is a good solution.

var app = angular.module('test', []);

app.controller('testctrl', function($scope) {

```
$scope.myDataset = [
{ seq: '1', },
{ seq: '2', },
{ seq: '3', },
{ seq: '4', },
{ seq: '2', },
{ seq: '', },
];

console.log($scope.myDataset);

console.log(_.unionBy(_.filter($scope.myDataset, function(o) {
  return !_.isEmpty(o.seq);
}), 'seq'));
```

});